# Why does the number of regions in a circle cut by chords joining $n+1$ points equal the number of regions in $\mathbb{R}^4$ cut by $n$ hyperplanes?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

It [is well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividing_a_circle_into_areas) that if $n+1$ points are placed on a circle ($n$ a nonnegative integer), the $\binom{n+1}{2}$ chords joining them cut the interior into
$$1 + \binom{n+1}{2} + \binom{n+1}{4} = \sum_{k=0}^4 \binom{n}{k}$$
regions (in the general case where no three chords have a common intersection). This is also equal to the number of regions that $4$-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^4$ is cut by $n$ general hyperplanes. (This is sequence [A000127](https://oeis.org/A000127).) (Equivalently, it is the number of regions cut by $n+1$ hyperplanes in $4$-dimensional projective space $\mathbb{RP}^4$.)

*The question:* Is there a direct proof that these two numbers are the same, without explicitly counting them? For example, is there a natural bijection between the regions in the circle and the regions in $4$-space?

Comment: You could first justify that both sequences are quartic polynomials, and then just calculate the first five terms. Unfortunately, that would be extremely boring and uninsightful.

Comment: Interesting question!  Just going from $n=1 \to 2$, the two regions are split differently into four in the two situations.  So any bijection between regions cannot be so simple that it survives "induction", in a vague sense...

Comment: Regarding the edit I rolled back, what I originally wrote is correct (the equality follows from $\binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n}{k-1} + \binom{n}{k}$). The right side comes from $\sum_{k=0}^d \binom{n}{k}$ being the number of regions in $\mathbb{R}^d$ cut by $k$ hyperplanes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put one marble inside each region and allow the marbles to fall and roll downwards, where we pick “downwards” as some direction that’s not parallel to anything of interest.

In the case of the circle:

- One marble rolls to the bottom of the circle.
- For every set of two points, one marble rolls to the lower of the two, resting on the chord between them.  (Each such marble actually rests between two chords, or between one chord and the upper part of circle; we assign it to the chord whose angle is farther from the upper part of the circle.)
- For every set of four points, one marble rolls to the intersection of the diagonals of the quadrilateral formed by them.

[image: picture]

This gives a bijection between the regions and the sets of 0, 2, or 4 of the $n + 1$ points.

In the case of 4-dimensional space, for convenience, draw an extra slightly slanted “ground hyperplane” below all of the existing intersection points that catches all the falling marbles (but does not create additional regions).

- One marble rolls forever down the ground hyperplane without hitting any other hyperplanes.
- For every set of two hyperplanes (possibly including the ground hyperplane), one marble rolls forever down the line or plane defined by the intersection of those hyperplanes with the ground hyperplane.
- For every set of four hyperplanes (possibly including the ground hyperplane), one marble rolls to their intersection.

This gives a bijection between the regions and the sets of 0, 2, or 4 of the $n + 1$ hyperplanes (possibly including the ground hyperplane).

Composing these bijections gives a bijection between the regions of the circle and the regions of 4-dimensional space.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what "below all of the existing intersections" means. Each intersection is a line, and the lines can be pointing every which way. So what is meant by "below all of the existing intersections"?

Comment: +1 I see. Where an "intersection point" is where any four of the hyperplanes meet. Got it.

Comment: It would be nice to define a "canonical" bijection between the hyperplanes and the points on the circle. Is there some "natural" way to do this? Perhaps with respect to the two "downward" directions? The circle points may be ordered from highest to lowest. Perhaps with the hyperplanes, assign to each a unit normal vector, dot with the unit vector in the "downward" direction, take absolute value to account for the two directions a normal vector could take, and order the hyperplanes according to that. The "floor"'s normal vector would have the largest dot product with "down".

Comment: @alex.jordan When a problem says you have $n$ things, that means you’re given as input a bijection between the things and $\{1, \dotsc, n\}$; you needn’t spend time re-counting them.

Comment: Well, I disagree. The $n$ things could come as an unordered set, and then there are $n!$ bijections to the ordered version. For example there are 8 Hawaiian islands, and there 8 US presidents who died in office. Which president corresponds to Maui? Of the $8!$ bijections, maybe one stands out as "natural". It's one thing to say a bijection exists, and another to actually give one.

Comment: If I drew a picture of a circle with $7$ dots and their chords, and then I "drew" a configuration of 6 hyperplanes, and showed it to you all at once, you'll have to come up with a mapping if you actually want to be able to tell me which particular region within the circle corresponds to which particular hyperregion.

My comment is just noting that "natural" orderings exist here, with respect to the "down" direction. So a "natural" map form the one set of $n+1$ things to the other set of $n+1$ things exists.

Comment: Nice. I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by "we assign it to the chord whose angle is farther from the upper part of the circle." Can you clarify this?

Comment: @arkeet I’ve added a picture showing the color-coded correspondence between chords (sets of 2 points) and their marbles. Does this help?

Comment: Ah, I think I see it - you choose the chord that is closer to the bottom point of the circle. Thanks!